# subprocess.CalledProcessError when trying to run Mallet with Gensim

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, lda, topic-modeling, mallet

I'm trying to do topic modeling with Gensim and Mallet ([link](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/topic-modeling-gensim-python/)). 
When I locate the mallet_path and then try to assign it to gensim, I get the error
    subprocess.CalledProcessError : returned non-zero exit status 1

And I get prompted to update Java (which I have done).

Any hints on how to solve it?

```
mallet_path = '/Users/username/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet'

ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=id2word)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#85>", line 1, in <module>
    ldamallet = gensim.models.wrappers.LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, num_topics=20, id2word=id2word)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py", line 132, in __init__
    self.train(corpus)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py", line 273, in train
    self.convert_input(corpus, infer=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/wrappers/ldamallet.py", line 262, in convert_input
    check_output(args=cmd, shell=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 1918, in check_output
    raise error
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '/Users/username/mallet-2.0.8/bin/mallet import-file --preserve-case --keep-sequence --remove-stopwords --token-regex "\S+" --input /var/folders/76/hdlh6w8d3nbb4m424wx3010w0000gn/T/adc98e_corpus.txt --output /var/folders/76/hdlh6w8d3nbb4m424wx3010w0000gn/T/adc98e_corpus.mallet' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Answer (score 0):

In bin directory, open the mallet file with a text editor then increase the MEMORY limit. It worked for me.